# CMake can't detect gcc built-in functions such as sqrt, pow ,exp and so on

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake, g++

I just wanna use the CMake to detect whether some built-in functions of GCC exist. So I used the `check_function_exists` command to do some checking works. Here is my code snippet in `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
include (CheckFunctionExists)
set (CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES math.h)
set (CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES m)
check_function_exists(sqrt HAVE_SQRT)
check_function_exists (pow HAVE_POW)
check_function_exists (exp HAVE_EXP)
check_function_exists (log HAVE_LOG)
```

> Code snippet in `TutorialConfig.h.in`

```
// the configured options and settings for Tutorial
#define Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR @Tutorial_VERSION_MAJOR@
#define Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR  @Tutorial_VERSION_MINOR@
#cmakedefine USE_MYMATH
#cmakedefine HAVE_SQRT
#cmakedefine HAVE_POW
#cmakedefine HAVE_LOG
#cmakedefine HAVE_EXP
```

However, directory when I executed  `Cmake`  command under my source directory. I got such error, weird.

```sh
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.0.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for sqrt
CMake Error: The source directory "../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/CheckFunctionExists.cmake:70 (try_compile):
  Failed to configure test project build system.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:23 (check_function_exists)
```

However, the directory claimed in the error message is indeed exists.

```sh
$ ls -la ../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp 
  total 0
  drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 14 21:41 .
  drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Apr 14 20:32 ..
```

I am not very expert in `CMake`, so I can't figure out what is the crux.

Here is [my log file outputed by CMake](https://gist.github.com/duanqiaobb/526e107df15b4fa315fdbf416c2b5d3f)

Hope anyone who is familiar with CMake gives me a hand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried creating the directory build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp by hand?

Comment: Hmm, no, because I have checked that the corresponding directory exists.I have updated the question.

Comment: Looks like you have specified *relative* paths for build and/or source directory in CMake GUI. It is better to use absolute ones.

Comment: Can you show the command you used to run CMake? Also, do you have any symbolic links in your directory structure (either in the source or build directory)? It also looks like you were using the release candidate of CMake 3.8.0, but it has been released now so you may want to switch to that and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, I did specify relative paths for build directory in my CMakeLists.txt. I will try your tips. Thanks.

Comment: @Tsyvarev You are right. The crux is the relative path specified in CMakeLists.txt, after I comment the corresponding configuration, everything goes well.But are there any way to make it work with relative path well? Because of the absolute paths are a little troublesome.

Comment: And can you answer it below, so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message

```
CMake Error: The source directory "../build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp" does not exist.
```

is possible if a *relative* path is used as a build directory.

While it is not explicitely stated in docs (and not checked by CMake itself), it is better to **use absolute path as build directory**.

---

Because **build directory** of the CMake project **isn't designed to be moved to other place** (or even on other machine), there is no reason for using relative path for it.